# How to completely set focus on a WebBrowser object in WPF

Tags: html, css, wpf, xaml, webbrowser-control

I have a basic class with a WebBrowser in it:

```
<Window x:Class="X.Y"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="X- Music Video"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="None">

    <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser1" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" Focusable="True"/>

</Window>
```

Then when I try to navigate to it, it works by opening a youtube video in fullscreen:

```
this.webBrowser1.NavigateToString(<html with youtube embedded>);
this.webBrowser1.Focus();
```

Example html:

```
<html>    <head>        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>        <style type="text/css">body, html{margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}#content{position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px;}</style>     </head>    <body>        <div id="content">            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QDfKzB2T0i4?autoplay=1&start=3"                </iframe>        </div>    </body></html>
```

The issue comes into play wherein the fullscreen view now isn't "focused". The `.Focus()` does enable keyboard focus, but not a **complete** activation. What ends up happening is there is a grey border on the top and left of the screen. Clicking in removes it and gives me complete focus though.

[image]

You can see it in the picture above, the 2-ish pixels wide grey border.

Is there anything I can do to improve on this? The whole project is on github, and you can download the `.exe` to run it from releases. It requires a Spotify account to work though, so hopefully this is reproducible enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually an HTML/CSS fix, instead of anything to do with c# or wpf.

The two things that need to be done is:

- Add `frameborder = "0"` to the iFrame
- Implement the following CSS `iframe:focus{ outline: none; }`

Once they're in place, you can create a seamless youtube embed.